# What is the purpose of using std::ios_base::trunc flag with std::ios_base::out

Tags: c++

What is the purpose of using `std::ios_base::trunc` flag with `std::ios_base::out`? I saw this in many examples.

I thought that it's guaranteed by the standard that `std::ios_base::out` also truncates the file (and all of the STL implementations which I know do this). Am I wrong and should explicitly notify that I want to truncate the file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, `std::ios_base::out` is equivalent to `"w"` in `fopen`.

The point of `std::ios_base::trunc` is when `std::ios_base::in` and `std::ios_base::out` are used the same time.

- `in | out` is equivalent to `"r+"`
- `in | out | trunc` is equivalent to `"w+"`
- `binary | in | out` is equivalent to `"rb+"`
- `binary | in | out | trunc` is equivalent to `"wb+"`

Maybe a table would be more obvious:

```
binary  in  out  trunc | stdio equivalent
-----------------------+-----------------
         +   +         |      "r+"
         +   +     +   |      "w+"
  +      +   +         |      "r+b"
  +      +   +     +   |      "w+b"
```

Comment: I don't understand you correctly about std::ios_base::binary. What do you mean? Should i explicitly specify std::ios_base::trunc with std::ios_base::binary?

Comment: @FrozenHeart Edited. `trunc` essentially means "I want to write first".

Comment: For bidirectional streams out is not equivalent to out|trunc. See P0W's answer.

Comment: "Yes, std::ios_base::out is equivalent to "w" in fopen." Where do you find it? I'm actually have checked even recent standard "https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4861.pdf". I can not find an exact description of the effect for "basic_ofstream". So personally, my opinion it is pretty unsafe to think to open only "std::ios_base::out" and assume that content will be definitely truncated.

Answer (score 4):

To replace a file's content rather than extending the file, it must be opened in

`std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::trunc`

For output file streams the open mode out is equivalent to `out|trunc`, that is, `trunc` flag can be omitted.

For bidirectional file streams, however, `trunc` must always be explicitly specified.

To extend an output file, flag `std::ios_base::ate | std::ios_base::app` is used.

Here, the file content is retained because the `trunc` flag is not set, and the initial file position is at the file's end.

However, additionally  `trunc` flag can be set, and the file content is discarded and the output is done at the end of an empty file.

Answer (score 1):

It is redundant - in other words, it makes no difference if you have it or not.

Obviously, in some combinations, such as `std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::in` it would NOT be redundant.